# How to check function for unlimited arguments ( ... args )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

if i have function :

```
function a( param:* , ... args ):void ;
a.length // 1


flash.utils.sdescribeType(a);
//return me informations only about first parameter , nothing about '... args'.
```

edit: avmplus.describeTypeJSON didnt help too.

So , is there any other way to check for unlimited arguments than try{} block and push lot of params ?

// edit for Kodiak

Comment: I don't get your sentence "even descibe type return me info only about first parameter".

Comment: I am afraid I am the same, with only getting information about the first parameter. I know of no other way. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can check it only inside the function.

```
Function().length
```

is returning you the defined parameters number which the function is willing to accept.

the ..args parameter is like you said unlimited. so there is no way you can check the length of it outside of the function.

you can do this only inside a function, so write some "bridge" function:

```
function bridgeToMain ( ...args ) : Number
{
    trace ( args.length );
    trace ( mainFunction.length );
}
```

Comment: but the problem is i need to know about it from outside of function to check how many parameters i can push throug it . From inside it would be clear and easy :)

Comment: @turbosqel But you can pass as many arguments as you like if you are using ...args. That is the whole point!

Comment: i know , but this is not a point . What i need is to know it in runtime , that funciton has unlimited arguments (... args) or not :] I like to check how many arguments i can apply to function limited by function.length or many as i want.

Comment: turbosqel I understand what you mean. (Perhaps you can check if the param type is an array?) However it's raising some alarm bells. There's probably a better way to go about what you're trying to achieve. Could you please provide a concrete example?

Comment: the thing what you want to do is only possible with try / catch statement.

Comment: @ richarddas - sorry , didnt saw Your message . What i exactly doing is function calling interface and i have to know how many params i can push to function.

Comment: but if you whiting the functions then you should know how many params you can parse. There is something wrong with desing of you applications.

Comment: but if they are not my functions but i have to call them ?